# 'popup closed by user' error on google sign in

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-signin, google-authentication

Im using google signin, and its working fine locally.  But when I put it on a server and try login i get

```
    'Uncaught: popup closed by user'
```

Ive disabled my adblocker, and anything that might be interfering.  But still get the error.

Im using Vuejs to login, and I know all the code works, because I can login locally just fine.

I'll post the code anyways, even though Im pretty sure this isnt where the issue lies. My Vue.js methods for login are...

```
 clickButton(type) {
  var that = this
  that.signType = type
  auth2.grantOfflineAccess({ 'redirect_uri': 'postmessage', 'approval_prompt': 'force' }).then(that.onSignIn);
},

// Callback for Sign In
onSignIn(authResult) {
  if (authResult.code) {
    this.$store.dispatch(TYPES.GET_GOOGLE_TOKEN, { code: authResult.code })
  }
},
```

Comment: If you click the login button again after the first attempt, does it still give you the same error?

Comment: Yes it does.  Same error no matter what I do.  Incognito window, disable adblocker, disable cookies.  Dunno what else to try

Comment: I had this same issue occurring, but in my case it's my browser default setting for popup blocker being set to "Continue blocking". The first click shows this warning on the right-hand side of the address bar, next subsequent clicks somehow ignore this setting and start displaying the Google Sign-in window.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced the same issue.
What i ended up doing was delete the oAuth app in Google console, and recreated it with all the Authorised URI correctly from the beginning (and not adding after creation).
this fixed the problem.

I think that once you add URI's to the Redirect/Authorised URI lists to an **existing** oAuth app in the google console - either it takes long time for the update to take place or it just doesn't work.